# Need a zip package that can run a web browser without installation

Tags: windows, web-browser

Like we can have executable packages for Intellij and Eclipse where we do not need to give a Installation, just we unzip the package and go to Application file of the software and click that, it launches the software(without its installation).

Need help for the similar zip which can help me in launching web browser as i dont have permission of installation and need a browser with no proxy on that.

Please help, really required urgently.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want a portable version of the browser, such as [Google Chrome Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet) from portableapps.com.

Portableapps.com is my go-to site for portable programs. I have used Google Chrome Portable and Firefox Portable and they work just like the full version, though you may have to update manually. There are also 11 other browsers you can choose from.

The file downloads as an EXE, not a ZIP, but it doesn't require administrative permissions to install. If that's a problem, you can also just extract the files from the EXE using [7zip](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable), as if it were a ZIP and not an EXE.

Comment: I tried with portable browser apps on portableapps.com . i saw that these are exe files. After that when i tried to run these it showed me "The application you are attempting to run is not permitted in this environment." 
But i am able to run portable intellij IDE exe file on my PC.
Main issue is that i want to use browser with no restrictions on that. Right now i have web browser but i cant even open gmail on that. i dont have access to open proxy settings in that browser.
I need a solution like a free account of browserling type of thing which provide live interactive cross browsing.